# Asus EA-N66 in Access Point Mode wont accept connections with an Asus router RT-AC87U, worked perfectly on RT-AC66U

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

As the title describes I'm having trouble connecting to access points with the new router. I have tried with APs in both Repeater Mode and Access Point(AP) mode. With my old router i could use the same SSID for router and AP so the first thing I tried was to set one of the APs to a different SSID but this does not work either. In the Wireless - Professional settings I have tried to set similar settings even though the AC87U have more options that I can not set in the EA-N66. Worth noting is that the the access poinst are given a local ip-address with the new router so that is not the problem.

What I have already tried with the AC87U:

- Roaming assistant - Enabled
- Enable IGMP Snooping - Enabled
- Reducing USB 3.0 interference - Enabled
- Enable Firewall - No

Any help is very appreciated and as the title says it works out of the box with my RT-AC66U router.

Comment: You don't really describe the problem really well. All you say is "wont accept connection" (but what does "accept" mean? what happens when you try?) and "does not work either". What *exactly* are you trying? And what *exactly* goes wrong when you try?

Comment: Hello David,
I will try to be more specific. When I try to connect with my laptop to the AP WIFI I get an error. On a Macbook Air it says: "Connection timed out". The routers wifi I can join without a problem. On my old router (RT-AC66U) I can join the APs wifi without a problem.